# CodeFirst migrations with different connection strings defined in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my asp.Net core (2.2) project, I've got

`appsettings.production.json`

`appsettings.staging.json`

`appsettings.development.json`

each with their own connection strings for different servers. I make a change to the models and run `Add-Migration` then `update-database` - but this only updates the schema on the development server.

How do I get it to target / update the staging and production servers using the connections defined in the environmental `appsettings.json` files?

I've tried building it using the different environments and when running in the different environments I know the connection strings are being used correctly - but how do I get EF to target specific databases!?

Answer (score 0):

You can set specfic enviroment using this command like this blog [mention](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/)

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

Then you just need to run dotnet ef migration cli command

Update make sure you already set your enviroment config like this in startup.cs

```
builder
    .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

You can view my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/Startup.cs)

Comment: I've been trying this, I was actually looking at that page already - I'm trying to run Update-Database etc. but it doesn't seem to work. I'm generating scripts and running them on the server in order to get all the previous migration history intact.

Comment: You mean it can not set an enviroment variable ?

Comment: The environment variable sets fine, but when trying to run the other commands it seems it's still referring to the DEV connection settings :/

Comment: Tried adding this and still get `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.` - it's always targeting Development server. I'm giving up on codefirst migrations, I'm not having a good experience with it. I've seen too many fundamental database design errors come through from colleagues just from bad model designs also.

Comment: Ok I'm very confused, it seems to have put in the tables except for the `migrations` table...